# Why I can use pointer of structure type before delaration

Tags: c, compiler-errors, operating-system

Why I can compile below code without any declaration?

```
struct node *n;

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I did'nt include any header.
Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer definition acts as a *forward declaration* of `struct node`.  Using such a declaration is allowed as long as the pointer isn't dereferenced before the actual struct definition appears.

This is necessary to allow constructs like this:

```
struct list_node {
    int value;
    struct list_node *next;
};
```

This is a typical definition of a node in a linked list.  The `next` field is of type `struct list_node *`, but at this point `struct list_node` has not yet been fully defined.  If such forward declarations were not allowed, such constructs would not be possible.

You can also use such a pointer to pass to a function and get a value returned.  For example:

```
struct node *n = new_node();
set_node_value(n, 1);
```

These two function could be defined in a separate source file where the full definition of `struct node` is known.  The structure in this case is an *opaque type* that users of a library don't need to know the details of.

Comment: I do not think it is helpful to describe this as a “*forward declaration*”. That is not a term used by the C standard, and “forward” does not convey any meaning to a student just encountering this concept—nothing is explained to them; there is no way for them to know what is forward of what or what concept is being conveyed by that. Simply, `struct list_node *n;` is a declaration of `n` as a pointer to a structure, and we know all we need to know about the pointer in order to be able to reserve space for it and such. So it is a complete type for `n` even if we do not know about the structure.